# Strategy for creating C# library for Third party integration with multiple wsdl versions

Tags: c#, api, soap, wsdl, multiple-versions

We need to integrate third party SOAP api with our system. As we are SaaS solution provider, we need to support all version of third party.
We have configuration that Customer A has version 1.8, Customer B has version 2.0. (Version may took months for new version.)

What I am looking for is a general strategy for creating a library that can work with all versions.

As a solution I think to create multiple namespace version wise in single C# library.

1. TP1.DLL

   - Namespace - TP1_v1.8

     - Entity1 (Proxy class)
     - Entity2 (Proxy class)
   - Namespace - TP2_v2.0

     - Entity1 (Proxy class)
     - Entity2 (Proxy class)

I want wrapper class for all entity irrespective of version. so i will call that wrapper class and it will initialize object with required version.

How can i do that ? Is it right way to handle a situation like this?

If any further information is needed, let me know!

Thanks!

Ankur Kalavadia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following solution for your problem which help to you in your implementation.

--> First you create common interface which can be usefull for common identifier of all the same types

--> Make Seperate  NameSpace by version name

```
 DefaultNameSpace : ABC.XYZ
 Version          : 1.6.2

Then make the namespace patterns as

e.g. ABC.XYZ.V162  (Replcing . and set prefix as per classname norms (always start with Alphabet ) )

Create Class under above namespace with implementing interface
```

--> Create same classname for all the versions ( e.g. class1 , class2 common in version v1, v2 with diferent implementation )

--> Create below common function to generate relevant object

```
    public static iTestInterface GetEntity(string className)
    {
        string versionPrefix = "v_";
        string strVersion =  1.6.2; 

        string dllPath =System.Web.HttpRuntime.BinDirectory; 
        string dllName = "dllName.dll";
        string Version = versionPrefix +  

        string strclassNameWithFullPath = dllPath + Version.Replace(".", "") + "." + className; 
        try
        {
            string strAssemblyWithPath = string.Concat(dllPath, dllName);

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(strAssemblyWithPath))
            {
                return null;
            }

            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(strAssemblyWithPath);
            Type t = assembly.GetType(strclassNameWithFullPath);

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            return (iTestInterface)obj;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //string errStr = string.Format("Error occured while late assembly binding. dllPath = {0}, dllName = {1}, className = {2}.", dllPath, dllName, className);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

-->  Call function as below

```
 iTestInterface obj = GetEntity(classnameString);
```

-->  call relevent object methods. Above call will be common for all relevant classes.

Thanks & Regards
Shailesh Chopra